# In Euclidean Neighborhood Retracts, the neighborhood have the $\mathbb{R}^n$ topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, open-map, retraction

I have $X$ retract by retraction $r$ of its open neighboorhood $Y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'd like to write that, if $O\subset X$ is an open set, so $r^{-1}(O)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But $r$ continuous only means that $r^{-1}(O)$ is an open set in $Y$. However, I feel that in this case the topology of $Y$ is the same that the one usual in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Could someone give me a light on this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If $X$ is only a subset of a Euclidean space, an open set within $X$ need not be Euclidean open, if that's what you're asking.  (It's hard to tell:  what exactly are $X$, $Y$, and $r$?)  For instance, I can only guess that $r: Y \to X$, but what is $X$?  And is $Y$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You can assume $Y$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then any subset $V\subset Y$ which is open in $Y$, is also open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (because of the definition of the relative topology).

Comment: @Randall, $X$ is an ENR (Euclidian Neighborhood Retract). Yes, yes, an open set within $X$ need not be Euclidian open, but I mean if the open set on the neighborhood is necessarily open, you see? Thank you so much. Yes, $Y$ is an open neighborhood.

Comment: @Tyrone, yes perfect! I just have a little doubt: On the definition of ENR I "can" assume that the neighborhood has the relative topology? Thank you so much.

Comment: This is the definition of neighbourhood.

Comment: That's simply perfect. If you wish, could you post as an answer to the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup is that there is an embedding $j:X\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, an open set $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $X\cong j(X)\subseteq Y$, and a continuous map $r:Y\rightarrow X$. The question regards the topology on $Y$. Suppose that $V\subset Y$ is any subset which is open in $Y$. Because $Y$ has the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$, this means that there is an open set $\widetilde V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V=\widetilde V\cap Y$. But $\widetilde V$ and $Y$ are both open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and hence so is their intersection $V$. In particular we can apply this when $V=r^{-1}(U)$ with $U\subseteq X$ open.